# In expressjs v4, how do i put timestamps on the logs?

Tags: node.js, express

I have tried to use morgan with the following

```
var morgan = require('morgan');
app.use(morgan('combined'));
```

But I get a response like this

```
www-0 ::1 - - [15/Apr/2016:10:43:13 +0000] "GET /dasda HTTP/1.1" 404 41 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.110 Safari/537.36"
www-0 GET / 304 4.624 ms - -
www-0 GET /font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css 304 1.953 ms - -
www-0 GET /css/common-561d902c.min.css 304 2.097 ms - -
www-0 GET /images/logo.png 304 3.072 ms - -
```

Why the logs `GET / 304 4.624 ms - -` and such are not affected by this? How can I put timestamps there?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried setting the format manually with `app.use(morgan(':date[clf] :id :method :url :response-time'))`

Comment: @RadoslavStoyanov yes, but it's the same output. What i want to achieve is like the one below. regardless of the date format.

`www-0 [15/Apr/2016:10:43:13 +0000] GET / 304 4.624 ms - -
www-0 [15/Apr/2016:10:43:13 +0000] GET /font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css 304 1.953 ms - -
www-0 [15/Apr/2016:10:43:13 +0000] GET /css/common-561d902c.min.css 304 2.097 ms - -
www-0 [15/Apr/2016:10:43:13 +0000] GET /images/logo.png 304 3.072 ms - -`

Comment: Can you search if any other package in your project overwrites somehow the morgan config?

Comment: @RadoslavStoyanov there is! thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: Great! I will post it as an answer and you can mark it to help anybody who face the same problem in the future :) I'm glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Search if any other package in your project overwrites somehow the `morgan's` configuration.